# Can I change size and shape of desktop shortcut icons in Win 7 pro

Tags: windows-7, desktop-computer

I would like to build a background image and set my desktop links to various sizes and shapes that would fit into that image. Can this be done with WIN 7?

Comment: What effect exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: AFAIK independent icon sizes is not possible, but maybe you can use something like [Fences](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/) to group similar icons (or those of the required colour or whatever) and place them on specific areas of your wallpaper.

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't let you have icons that are different sizes. Though if you right click your desktop, and mouse over "view", you're given some options:

```
 - Large icons
 - Medium icons
 - Small icons
---------------------
 - Auto arrange icons
 - Align icons to grid
----------------------
 - Show desktop icons
```